# Why firebase phone auth requires a custom URL scheme to be registered in Xcode?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If my understanding is right, custom URL schemes are registered to launch the app using a different url. For example: if custom scheme `foo` is registered, then the app can be launched using `foo://<params>` url.

If that is the case, why firebase phone auth requires registering a custom URL scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Auth for iOS requires a custom scheme in case an APNs token is not available for whatever reason. This is needed since phone auth in iOS relies on push notifications for security purposes. In that case, it will fallback to a reCAPTCHA flow. A webpage in a SFSafariViewController is launched serving a reCAPTCHA and on successful resolution, will redirect back to the app via a custom URL scheme redirect.