# How should I go about adding a Custom URL Scheme to my Info.plist file for firebase phone auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

This question is in relation to [Why firebase phone auth requires a custom URL scheme to be registered in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867392/why-firebase-phone-auth-requires-a-custom-url-scheme-to-be-registered-in-xcode)

I have tried a couple of things to add Custom URL Scheme to my Info.plist to no luck

I added the following lines to my Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.googleusercontent.apps</string> 
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>apps.{{CLIENT_ID}}</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

EDIT:
Solved the problem by modifying the above lines like this

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.{{CLIENT_ID}}</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add it in Info > Url Types like so:

[image]

More details here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#set-up-recaptcha-verification